# How to exclude a system library from dynamic linking

Tags: dll, linker

I have a local DLL which I want to shadow the system one.
How do i do that?

Specifically (on linux):

```
/usr/bin/clang++ -o vw main.o -L. -l vw -l allreduce -L /usr/lib -L /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -l boost_program_options -l pthread -l z
```

but then

```
$ ldd vowpalwabbit/vw
        libvw.so => /usr/lib64/libvw.so (0x00007ffa22789000)
```

and I want it to point to `./libvw.so` instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Afaik the parameter is -nostdlib, but I only used it with plain C.

See also [Clang produces crashing code with -nostdlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21631579/clang-produces-crashing-code-with-nostdlib)